# How to to obtain a "takeout" style export of a reddit account?

Tags: reddit, export, migrate-data

I'd like to save references and copies to/of all the comments, and submissions made by the account, as well as a listing of upvoted/downvoted links, in addition to private messages, in a user-friendly and presentable format, kind of like how facebook account exports work with styled HTML files in a .zip archive.

What's the closest one can come to this?

Answer (score 5):

There is unfortunately no in house option from Reddit itself, nor are there any 3rd party apps that allow this.

However, using the Reddit API, you could use: 
http://www.reddit.com/user/karmanaut/overview.json

or to return in XML format:
http://www.reddit.com/user/karmanaut/overview.xml

Of course you can fetch just your comments or your submitted links:

```
→ /user/username/overview
→ /user/username/submitted
→ /user/username/comments
→ /user/username/liked
→ /user/username/disliked
→ /user/username/hidden
→ /user/username/saved
→ /user/username/gilded
```

For message threads this would be:

/message/where[ .json | .xml ]

```
→ /message/inbox
→ /message/unread
→ /message/sent
```

E.g. http://www.reddit.com/message/inbox.json

Full documentation can be found here: http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_user_%7Busername%7D_about.json

Comment: How about private message threads?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Can you think of any other things that one might want to have in a reddit account "takeout", both things and listings that are publicly viewable, and those that aren't?

Comment: Also... you have any idea about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763883/requesting-elaboration-on-the-reddit-api-listing-endpoints-count-parameter)?

Answer (score 0):

Btw, I implemented a tool for that: https://github.com/karlicoss/rexport. It only cares about exporting data, so rendering to HTML need to be handled separately.